# Increasing height of UIView and changing background colour - can't make it work

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview

I've drawn a `UIView` (scrollInner) in Interface Builder and I now want to increase its height programmatically and also change its background colour.

The `UIView` is inside a `UIScrollView`, and the scrolling all works fine. Basically, what I'm doing is trying to increase the inner `UIView` so it matches the contentSize of the `UIScrollView`.

Here's what I've got so far in my `viewDidAppear` method:

```
CGRect scrollInnerRect = self.scrollInner.frame;
scrollInnerRect.size.height = 1000;
self.scrollInner.frame = scrollInnerRect;
[self.scrollInner setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

The background colour of the `UIView` changes to red as expected, but the height of the 'UIView' remains the same size as it was set in Interface Builder.

However, if I do this:

```
NSLog(@"My uiview's frame is: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(scrollInner.frame));
```

I get this in the log:

```
My uiview's frame is: {{0, 150}, {320, 1000}}
```

...which suggests that the `UIView`'s height has been increased.

But that's not how it appears in the simulator. In other words, on screen the `UIView` is coloured red, but DOES NOT have the new height of 1000px - it's still way shorter.

Any ideas where I might be going wrong?

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

check whether u have Autolayout enabled if so remove the spacing  .and incerase the height of subview by view.frame = CGrectMake(x,y,yourwidth,yourincreasedheight)

Comment: Thanks - what do you mean by 'remove the spacing'? I've also tried increasing the height in the way you describe and I get the same result.

Comment: you have autolayout enabled ?

Comment: it seems your uiview is connected to other views using autolayout . check to which one it is and remove the clipping to that view.You have to remove the constraints try[yourview removeConstraints:yourview.constraints];

Comment: thanks, it works as expected with autolayout off. But I need autolayout on to manage other things in the view. How do I check to see which other views the UIView is connected to?

Answer (score 0):

You can add connection in interface builder from your UIView to your class extension to create properties. And after that you can make the changes in code like that.

```
self.myView.frame = self.scrollInner.contentSize.
```

And you can change your UIView colour like that:

```
[self.myView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Comment: Thanks - I have no problem with changing the colour. My problem is that the height of the subview won't change!

Comment: Try replace this line self.scrollInner.frame = scrollInnerRect;  with that line: self.scrollInner.contentSize = scrollInnerRect;

Comment: That won't work as UIView objects don't have a contentSize property.

Comment: Sorry I thought that scrollInner is in type of UIScrollView. can you make sure that your scrollView content size is set with height = 1000 as well. I believe your uiview has height = 1000 but your scrollView had content size less than that and you cannot see it.

Comment: Sorry, yes, scrollInner is a UIView. I have already set the UIScrollView's contentSize property to a height of 1000 which is equal to the desired height of the inner UIView, and I can definitely scroll to that distance - so that does work as expected. The problem is that scrollInner's height does not increase.

Comment: Some more info - the UIView has a height of around 400px in IB. I'm trying to change this to 1000px so it matches the UIScrollView's contentSize, and turn the background red. Once I scroll past the 400px position, the UIView ends and I see the superView's background through the transparent UIScrollView.

Basically, I need the UIView to hide this!

Comment: Make sure your UIView in storyboard is set up right. Maybe There is some constraint which cause this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the 'use Autolayout' property in the identity inspector check your outlets properly in the xib file after that write this code :

```
CGRect scrollInnerRect = self.scrollInner.frame;

scrollInnerRect.size.height = CGrectMake(x,y,320,1000);
```

Comment: I want to use Autolayout.

Answer (score 0):

You might have fixed this issue. This may help others.

We can create and hold the reference of `NSLayoutConstraint` for the view height.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint * scrollInnerHeightConstraint;
```

And we can use this height constraint to update the view height wherever we need

```
scrollInnerHeightConstraint.constant = 1000;//1000 is your height
scrollInnerHeightConstraint.priority = 1000;//1000 is High priority
```

Comment: I have the same problem - the frame of the UIView is changed correctly, but the "expanded" part of the UIView is transparent. 

How does creating an NSLayoutConstraint property help?