# UIView background color not redrawn when frame changes (in dynamically expanding TableViewCell)

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, uiviewcontroller, autolayout

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` with an `UIView` in the background, and a `UITextView` on top.

The `UIView` is used to set the background color to white, with rounded edges to reveal the cell's `contentView.backgroundColor` (red) in the corners.

The `UITextView` height expands correctly when the user enters text.

The `UIView` (highlighted in the screenshot) has constraints on all 4 sides to grow together with the UITableViewCell. This works correctly (see screenshot, I also checked the frame height).

The problem is that the white `UIView.backgroundColor` is not expanded, so the "expanded" part is transparent, letting the red `contentView.backgroundColor` show.

I have tried to call `setNeedsLayout` on the `UIView` and/or the `UITableViewCell` in `UITextViewDelegate textViewDidChange`, but this did not solve the issue.

Also, setting the background colors in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` or `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath` does not make a difference.

This seems to be similar to this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20283216/increasing-height-of-uiview-and-changing-background-colour-cant-make-it-work).

**How can I have the `UIView backgroundColor` draw on the whole updated, expanded frame, and not just the original frame?**

[image: Screenshot]

Update 2018-06-20:

Here is what I'm doing to get the rounded corners (from [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847163/round-two-corners-in-uiview/14485362))

```
// from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847163/round-two-corners-in-uiview/14485362
- (void)setMaskTo:(id)sender byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCorner)corners withCornerRadii:(CGSize)radii {
    // UIButton requires this
    [sender layer].cornerRadius = 0.0;

    UIBezierPath *shapePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:[sender bounds]
                                                    byRoundingCorners:corners
                                                          cornerRadii:radii];

    CAShapeLayer *newCornerLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    newCornerLayer.frame = [sender bounds];
    newCornerLayer.path = shapePath.CGPath;
    [sender layer].mask = newCornerLayer;
}
```

Then, in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` I call it with

```
[self setMaskTo:textInputCell.bgColorView byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight) withCornerRadii:CORNER_RADII];
```

Comment: You need to change the constraints dynamically while changing the frame.

Comment: Can you explain further? Currently, I don't change the frame explicitly in code.

Comment: @thomers - How are you "rounding the corners" of your white UIView? Are you setting its `layer.cornerRadius`? Or are you setting a layer path?

Comment: @DonMag I'm setting a layer path - see my update. Am I right assuming that the problem is that I'm only setting the path once, and not updating it? If so, where/how should I update it? Or get rid of the UIBezierPath and do something else entirely? (Note that I want to define which specific corners I'm rounding)

Comment: (Revisiting the referenced SO answers about rounding specific corners, I see I could use iOS 11's CACornerMask instead of setting a bezierPathWithRoundedRect)

Comment: I can confirm that commenting out setting the layer mask fixes the problem - the UIView is growing and redrawn correctly.

Comment: @DonMag As assumed, I could fix this problem by setting layer.maskedCorners to a CACornerMask instead of creating the CAShapeLayer explicitly in code. If you want to write this as the answer, I will accept it (otherwise I will answer it myself in a few days)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, if you're targeting iOS 11+ you can use `CACornerMask` (`layer.maskedCorners`) which allows you to specify specific corners to be rounded.

If you need to support iOS 10 or earlier, you can put your `UIBezierPath` code in `layoutSubviews()` - that way, you can update its frame anytime the view's frame changes.